# Setting an unmanaged image via int array

Tags: c#, image, aforge

I have an array of 8 bytes, in which I want to put it into a length 4 (downwards) by width 2 (rightwards) bitmap. My code:

```
unsafe
{
    IntPtr pixels = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8);

    Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 0 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 0);
    Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 1 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 255);
    Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 2 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 0);
    Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 3 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 255);

    Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 4 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 0);
    Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 5 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 0);
    Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 6 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 0);
    Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 7 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 0);

    var newImage = new UnmanagedImage(pixels, 2, 4, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    var myBM = newImage.ToManagedImage();
    myBM.Save("outputBM.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pixels);
}
```

The issue is that for the first column, the image corresponds to my array:

[image]

However if I try to change:

```
Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 4 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 0);
```

to

```
Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 4 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 255);
```

I would expect the pixel in the 2nd column, 1st row to change to white. However this does not happen. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `stride` constructor parameter value of the `new UnmanagedImage()` equal to 2.

> stride: Image stride (line size in bytes).

By changing the following line:

```
var newImage = new UnmanagedImage(pixels, 2, 4, 2, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

the code will produce the following image:

[image]

When you change:

```
Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 4 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 0);
```

to

```
Marshal.WriteByte(pixels, 4 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Byte)), 255);
```

The image produced will look as follows:

[image]